# Injecting spring dependencies into Domain objects best practices?

Tags: spring, dns

I've scraped all over many resources, and have made this work and it's kinda complex, which turns me into asking for review and other ideas on how to properly inject spring dependencies into DomainObjects ..

My solution so far includes ..

**Defining the dependencies needed for loadweaving**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**And then .. configure it in the spring context file :**

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:load-time-weaver/>
```

**Using @Configurable for my domain classes :**

```
@Configurable
public class MyDomainClass {
    ....
}
```

**And of course, using these VM arguments :**

```
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier -javaagent:C:/Users/albert/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-instrument-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
```

For this current solution, i have the feeling that this seems too much, like the lots of dependencies needed, and also the VM args, which i would dislike when deploying in production server where i have to use specific options, which i fear could be not supported in the future or perhaps have different behaviours between version.

Im thinking of doing domainObjects with prototype scope, but i fear the dependencies issues when fetching the domain objects from the database (not from applicationContext).

Please share your experiences, thank you !

Comment: What are you injecting into your domain objects?

Comment: @DaveNewton : Im injecting a unit of work (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) which is of request scope

Comment: I'd be *very* cautious taking this approach--I don't know precisely what you're trying to do, but it sounds like something is a bit backwards.

Comment: @DaveNewton: May i ask why ? Let's go to a simple example, where a domain object has data and behaviours. One of the behaviours makes use of a strategy pattern where the behaviour can have multiple implementations. I define the implementation in the spring appcontext. How can i 'inject' the implementation defined in spring appcontext into the domain model ?

Answer (score 3):

1: When you start injection stuff dynamically into domain objects, they're really not domain objects any more in the sense that the domain should reflect your information model, independent of any business rules and functional logic.

2: Remember KISS (keep it simple...). At some point, someone else might have to take ownership and maintain your code so have some mercy on that person :)

I would call this an anti-pattern, which in my opinion should be avoided.

Comment: In my case, actually it's quite simple. The version of my domain model encapsulates both data and behaviour. And for some behaviour, it's going to access a bean in a spring applicationContext. But what are the options to access that bean .. ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use compile time waving, then you will not need the VM argument.

Comment: Thanks, i'll research more on this.

Comment: @Albert Kam  it is easy http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable, and if you use maven, then you only need to add the aspectj compiler